# How to continually add typed characters to a variable?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to know how to add the character a user pressed to a variable without erasing the variables previous data. For example, when a user types `a` it adds `a` to a variable. Then the user types `t` and it adds `t` to the variable, but it saves the a, so now the variable is a string containing `at`. I have tried for quite awhile now and still can not figure out how to do this.

Comment: You are talking about arrays.

Comment: @sємsєм No because if you try to display the array with `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = your_array;` it displays it like this: `a,t,etc.,`

Comment: Sorry, I don't, clearly, understand your last comment. However, your question is the definition of an array.

Comment: @sємsєм The comment sent early sorry for that.

Comment: I think he means something more like `var = var + 'a'`

Comment: You have to make `your_array` as a concatenated string which gets its value from a `loop` through the array.

Comment: @HittmanA can you add some additional info? Maybe some code of what you have tried already? Also how these users add characters, from and input field or by clicking buttons, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `oninput` event, create a variable that is `undefined`, at first `input` event, set `window[variable]` and created variable to character user input; at subsequent input from user, concatenate `window[variable]` from last character at user input using `String.prototype.slice()` with parameter `-1`

```js
var q = void 0;

document.querySelector("input").oninput = function(e) {
  if (!q && !window[e.target.value]) {
    window[e.target.value] = q = e.target.value;
  } else {
    window[q] += e.target.value.slice(-1);
    console.log(window[q])
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```